# Program stops working when printing the content of a matrix

Tags: c

This is a very simple program. It reads a matrix of size mn, and then it is supossed to print the even rows backwards and the even rows normally, asumming the row 0 is the row 1 and so on. For some reason it just stops working. I hope someone can point my error, i have tried  a lot of solutions but none of them seems to work. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int m,n,i,j;
    int **a;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
                    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        if((m+1)%2==0){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(j=n;j!=0;j--){
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Others have pointed out the most likely cause of your crash. However I would strongly suggest that you check the results of your input operations. For example if the person presses Enter or ^D or types words instead of numbers for the first input line, then your program is going to go haywire. You should also check that `malloc` did not return NULL.

Comment: Also, `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour. Maybe your compiler treats it as discarding unread input, but others don't. On my system it just does nothing (although this actually makes your program easier to use, as I can input "2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6" for example, instead of pressing enter after each number).

A portable way to flush input is: `int ch; while ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');`

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is weird, but deleting the `fflush(stdin);` line fixed this. I have never had this issue before. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){ // <==
    a[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
                }
```

you have to allocate a total of `m` arrays, not `n`

Then adjust

```
for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){
```

`j` must stay between `0` and `n-1`

**Edit:**

You have another error here:

```
    if((m+1)%2==0){  // <-- wrong
```

correct is

```
    if((i+1)%2==0){
```

If you count rows assuming the first one is odd (nr. 1) that will eveluates true for even rows (those that will be printed normally)

---

By the way:

1) you should get familiar with the use of a debugger. You'd spot these bugs immediately. (And you shouldn't use Stack Overflow as a "please debug my code service". But I'm happy to give help..)

2) you should not cast the return value of `malloc`, for example

```
a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

3) you should free up the allocated memory at the end of the program:

```
    free(a);  // <-----
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: all allocated memory is needed for the whole execution of the program. When the program ends memory is released automatically. However I agree it's a good practice to always free allocated memory. It's an even better practice to ensure `malloc` succeds checking that it doesn't returns null.

Comment: @Paolo Well, none of this seem to work. Also, allocating the matrix that way seem to make it the wrong size.

Comment: It's up to the C implementation and operating system whether un-freed memory is automatically freed at the end or not.  I have used systems where it is not.

Answer (score 0):

As Paolo said, you are allocating a total of `n` arrays but you need to allocate `m`. At line 9 in your code, this for:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```

must run from `0` to `m` not `n`

Plus the other adjustment Paolo mentioned, the one related to the value of `j`.

And I think you may get trouble with your "even or not" validation since you´re using `m` which value never changes, using `i` will do the trick.